# what are the new features in the red5 1.0.2?what are the pros and cons of using red5 1.0.1 instead?

Tags: java, red5

I am just starting learning red5 server and I am confused what version of red5 should I use?

I want to use the android app as a client for red 5.I have the following queries.

1. Is it supported in red5 version 1.0.1.
2. What the the benefits/new features of using red5 version 1.0.2?Is it stable?
3. Are there any cons of using red5 version 1.0.1.(If the answer to my first question is yes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, minor releases contain bug fixes and improvements that do not break any API published in a major release.

I do not know about the exact details of Red5, but my advice is to read the [Red5 Changelog](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/doc/trunk/changelog.txt). Additionally, you can use the link in the changelog to the issue management system to get more detailed information.

Comment: Though wasn't an exact answer to my question yet the info helped me taking the decision and get started.Thanks